# Control options in Select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have the select box and created in HTML page as like below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><select id="gagaga">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
 <option>D</option>
<option>E</option>
<option>F</option></select></body></html>
```

Now my question is ,In dropdownbox I need to show A,B,C values and i need to show D,E,F values on scroll bar moves?

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple options to be selected?, thinking you may be looking for multiple select

Comment: In fact you can just add attribute size of 3...no need to have it as multiple select if you only want to select one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add size Attribute to select Element

```
<select id="gagaga" onmousedown="this.size=3;" onblur="this.size=1;">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
    <option>F</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if i use the size , the select box size will be set as 3.by default it will be shows 3 values.

Comment: I need to show first three values on drop down arrow click.remaining 3 I need to show the scroll bar's down drag

Comment: @User I've update my answer... please check if that is what you're looking for

Comment: @User I think this answers what you are looking for.